# Morphisms of sheaves coming from divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a non-singular irreducible complex projective variety and $D$ is an effective divisor on $X$.

1) Assume $i:D\hookrightarrow X$ is smooth. suppose we have a surjection of sheaves on $X$ of the form $E\twoheadrightarrow i_*F$ where $E$ and $F$ are vector bundles on $X$ and $D$ of the same rank. Then is it true that $E|_D\simeq F$?

2) Suppose $mD$ denotes the non-reduced divisor obtained by thickening $D$ $m$ times. Then $D$ is a closed subscheme of $mD$. If $L$ is a line bundle on $D$ will the push forward of $L$ to $mD$ be a torsion sheaf? I remember seeing somewhere that it is a line bundle. I am not able to justify this. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to 1) is yes. Indeed, the restriction functor is right exact, hence there is a surjection $E\vert_D \to F$ of vector bundles of the same rank. Consequently, it is an isomorphism. By the way, the assumption of smoothness of $D$ is unnecessary here.

The answer to 2) depends on the definition of a torsion sheaf you use. But anyway, the pushforward of $L$ to $mD$ is not a line bundle.

Comment: thank you, how can we think of the push forward of $L$ to $mD$. What is it's determinant?

Comment: Its determinant is not defined because this sheaf is not a perfect complex.